# ddl is reverting on postbacks

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

so I've been developing an asp.net web site and it has cascading dropdown. I didn't use ajax extender for cascading dropdown. here is the html mark up of my project

SPOILER, it has lot and lot of checkboxes, that's why i really need to have a workaround for checkboxes or postbacks..

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 

    <div class = "header" runat = "server">
    <div class = "osv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "center">
    <div class = "box">
        <table id = "spot"> 
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBLPlatform" runat="server" Text="Platform :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPlatform" runat="server" CssClass = "ddl" AutoPostBack="True" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="Platform" Value="Platform" ></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="First Person" Value="F1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="3rd Person" Value="F3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Role Playing" Value="RP"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Multiplayer" Value="MP"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Single Player" Value="SP"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> 
            </td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBLDate" runat="server" Text="Date :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="DDLDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBLAgency" runat="server" Text="Agency :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLAgency" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  CssClass = "ddl" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Agency"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBLReference" runat="server" Text="Reference :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID = "TXTReference" runat = "server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBLAdvertiser" runat="server" Text="Advertiser :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLAdvert" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass = "ddl" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Advertiser" ></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID = "LBLProgram" runat = "server" Text = "Program"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID = "DDLProg" runat = "server" CssClass = "ddl"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID = "LBLProduct" runat = "server" Text = "Product :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLProd" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass = "ddl" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Product"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID = "LBLTeldate" runat = "server" Text = "Telecast Date :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" onclick="return datepicker_onclick()" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBLVerleng" runat="server" Text="Version/Length :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLVer" runat="server" CssClass = "ddl" EnableViewState="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True"> </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBLAe" runat="server" Text="Account Executive :"></asp:Label></td>

            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TXTAe" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LBLCost" runat="server" Text="Cost :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TXTCost" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

this is my code behind where it loads the cascading ddls

```
 Protected Sub dbchose() Handles DDLPlatform.SelectedIndexChanged
    If IsPostBack Then

        Select Case DDLPlatform.SelectedValue
            Case "Platform"
                DDLAgency.DataSource = New List(Of String)
                DDLAgency.DataBind()
                DDLAgency.Items.Add("Agency")
                DDLAdvert.DataSource = New List(Of String)
                DDLAdvert.DataBind()
                DDLAdvert.Items.Add("Advertiser")
                DDLProd.DataSource = New List(Of String)
                DDLProd.DataBind()
                DDLProd.Items.Add("Product")
                DDLVer.DataSource = New List(Of String)
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version - Length")
                DDLProg.DataSource = New List(Of String)
                DDLProg.DataBind()
                DDLProg.Items.Add("Program")
            Case "F1"
                Session("platform") = "F1"
                Dim conn As New SqlConnection(Session("cs").ToString)
                Dim que As String = "Select ag_agencde, ag_agennme from agency where ag_stat= 'A' order by ag_agennme asc"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open() 'loading of agency per platform
                DDLAgency.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
                DDLAgency.DataTextField = "ag_agennme"
                DDLAgency.DataValueField = "ag_agencde"
                DDLAgency.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '-- Loading List of Program per Platform - BMS
                Dim que2 As String = "select pg_prgcode, pg_prgname from program where pg_status='A' order by pg_prgname ASC"
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que2, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProg.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLProg.DataTextField = "pg_prgname"
                DDLProg.DataValueField = "pg_prgcode"
                DDLProg.DataBind()
                conn.Close()

                '--
            Case "F3"
                Session("platform") = "F3"

                Dim conn As New SqlConnection(Session("cs").ToString)
                Dim que As String = "Select ag_agencde, ag_agennme from agency where ag_stat='A' order by ag_agennme asc"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open() 'loading of agency per platform
                DDLAgency.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
                DDLAgency.DataTextField = "ag_agennme"
                DDLAgency.DataValueField = "ag_agencde"
                DDLAgency.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--loading of F3 programs
                Dim que2 As String = "select pg_prgcode, pg_prgname from program where pg_status = 'A' order by pg_prgname ASC "
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que2, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProg.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLProg.DataTextField = "pg_prgname"
                DDLProg.DataValueField = "pg_prgcode"
                DDLProg.DataBind()
                '--
            Case "RP"
                Session("platform") = "RP"

                Dim conn As New SqlConnection(Session("cs").ToString)
                Dim que As String = "Select ag_agencde, ag_agennme from agency where ag_stat='A' order by ag_agennme asc"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open()
                '--
                DDLAgency.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
                DDLAgency.DataTextField = "ag_agennme"
                DDLAgency.DataValueField = "ag_agencde"
                DDLAgency.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--loading of program per plaform - News TV
                Dim que2 As String = "select pg_prgcode, pg_prgname from program where pg_status='A' order by pg_prgname ASC"
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que2, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProg.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLProg.DataTextField = "pg_prgname"
                DDLProg.DataValueField = "pg_prgcode"
                DDLProg.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
            Case "MP"
                Session("platform") = "Radio"

                Dim conn As New SqlConnection(Session("cs").ToString)
                Dim que As String = "Select ag_agencde, ag_agennme from agency where ag_stat='A' order by ag_agennme asc"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open()
                '--
                DDLAgency.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
                DDLAgency.DataTextField = "ag_agennme"
                DDLAgency.DataValueField = "ag_agencde"
                DDLAgency.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--loading of program for radio
                Dim que2 As String = "select pg_prgcode, pg_prgname from program where pg_stat='A' order by pg_prgname ASC"
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que2, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProg.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLProg.DataTextField = "pg_prgname"
                DDLProg.DataValueField = "pg_prgcode"
                DDLProg.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
            Case "SP"
                Session("platform") = "SP"

                Dim conn As New SqlConnection(Session("cs").ToString)
                Dim que As String = "Select ag_agencde, ag_agennme from agency where ag_stat='A' order by ag_agennme asc"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open()
                '--
                DDLAgency.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
                DDLAgency.DataTextField = "ag_agennme"
                DDLAgency.DataValueField = "ag_agencde"
                DDLAgency.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--loading of programs Pinoy TV
                Dim que1 As String = "select pg_prgcode, pg_prgname from program where pg_status='A' order by pg_prgname ASC"
                Dim cm2 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProg.DataSource = cm2.ExecuteReader
                DDLProg.DataTextField = "pg_prgname"
                DDLProg.DataValueField = "pg_prgcode"
                DDLProg.DataBind()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub agen_choose() Handles DDLAgency.SelectedIndexChanged

    If IsPostBack = True Then
        Select Case Session("platform").ToString
            Case "F1"
                Dim que As String = "select ad_advcde, ad_advnme from advertiser where ad_stat='A'  order by ad_advnme ASC"
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLAdvert.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLAdvert.DataTextField = "ad_advnme"
                DDLAdvert.DataValueField = "ad_advcde"
                DDLAdvert.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                ''--

            Case "F3"
                Dim cs As String = "server=SQLREP;database=F3;uid=sa;password=sa;"
                conn.ConnectionString = cs
                Dim que As String = "select ad_advcde, ad_advnme from advertiser where ad_stat='A' order by ad_advnme ASC"
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLAdvert.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLAdvert.DataTextField = "ad_advnme"
                DDLAdvert.DataValueField = "ad_advcde"
                DDLAdvert.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--


            Case "RP"
                Dim que As String = "select ad_advcde, ad_advnme from RPSA.advertiser where ad_stat='A' order by ad_advnme ASC"
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLAdvert.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLAdvert.DataTextField = "ad_advnme"
                DDLAdvert.DataValueField = "ad_advcde"
                DDLAdvert.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
            Case "Radio"
                Dim que As String = "select ad_advcde, ad_advnme from advertiser where ad_stat='A' order by ad_advnme ASC"
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLAdvert.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLAdvert.DataTextField = "ad_advnme"
                DDLAdvert.DataValueField = "ad_advcde"
                DDLAdvert.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
            Case "SP"
                Dim que As String = "select ad_advcde, ad_advnme from SPSA.advertiser where ad_stat='A' order by ad_advnme ASC"
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(que, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLAdvert.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                DDLAdvert.DataTextField = "ad_advnme"
                DDLAdvert.DataValueField = "ad_advcde"
                DDLAdvert.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub adver_choose() Handles DDLAdvert.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(Session("cs").ToString)
    If IsPostBack = True Then
        Select Case Session("platform").ToString
            Case "F1"
                Dim que3 As String = "select p_pcode, p_pname from product where p_stat = 'A' and p_advcde = " & DDLAdvert.SelectedValue & " order by p_pname asc"
                Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(que3, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProd.DataSource = cmd3.ExecuteReader
                DDLProd.DataTextField = "p_pname"
                DDLProd.DataValueField = "p_pcode"
                DDLProd.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLProd.Items.Add("Product")
                '--
            Case "F3"
                Dim que3 As String = "select p_pcode, p_pname from product where p_stat='A' and p_advcde = " & DDLAdvert.SelectedValue & " order by p_pname asc"
                Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(que3, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProd.DataSource = cmd3.ExecuteReader

                DDLProd.DataTextField = "p_pname"
                DDLProd.DataValueField = "p_pcode"
                DDLProd.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLProd.Items.Add("Product")
                '--
            Case "RP"
                Dim que3 As String = "select p_pcode, p_pname from RPSA.product where p_stat='A' and p_advcde = " & DDLAdvert.SelectedValue & " order by p_pname asc"
                Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(que3, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProd.DataSource = cmd3.ExecuteReader
                DDLProd.DataTextField = "p_pname"
                DDLProd.DataValueField = "p_pcode"
                DDLProd.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLProd.Items.Add("Product")

                '--
                '--
            Case "Radio"
                Dim que3 As String = "select p_pcode, p_pname from product where p_stat='A' and p_advcde = " & DDLAdvert.SelectedValue & " order by p_pname asc"
                Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(que3, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProd.DataSource = cmd3.ExecuteReader
                DDLProd.DataTextField = "p_pname"
                DDLProd.DataValueField = "p_pcode"
                DDLProd.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLProd.Items.Add("Product")
                '--
                '--
            Case "SP"
                Dim que3 As String = "select p_pcode, p_pname from SPSA.product where p_stat='A' and p_advcde = " & DDLAdvert.SelectedValue & " order by p_pname asc"
                Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(que3, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLProd.DataSource = cmd3.ExecuteReader
                DDLProd.DataTextField = "p_pname"
                DDLProd.DataValueField = "p_pcode"
                DDLProd.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLProd.Items.Add("Product")
                '-- 
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub get_prod_ver() Handles DDLProd.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(Session("cs").ToString)
    If Not IsPostBack = True Then
        Select Case Session("platform").ToString
            Case "F1"
                Dim que1 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd4.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
                '--
            Case "F3"
                Dim que1 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd4.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()

                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
                '--
            Case "RP"
                Dim que1 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from RPSA.version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from RPSA.product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd4.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
            Case "Radio"
                Dim que1 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd4.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
            Case "SP"
                Dim que11 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from SPSA.version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from RPSA.product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd41 As New SqlCommand(que11, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd41.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
        End Select
    Else
        Select Session("platform").ToString
            Case "F1"
                Dim que1 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.ClearSelection()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd4.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
                '--
            Case "F3"
                Dim que1 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.ClearSelection()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd4.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()

                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
                '--
            Case "RP"
                Dim que1 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from RPSA.version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from RPSA.product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.ClearSelection()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd4.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
            Case "Radio"
                Dim que1 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(que1, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.ClearSelection()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd4.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
            Case "SP"
                Dim que11 As String = "select v_version +' Lenght:' + convert(varchar(10), v_spotlen) as 'Version And Lenght', v_vpcode from SPSA.version where v_vpcode = (select p_pcode from RPSA.product where p_pcode='" & DDLProd.SelectedValue & "')"
                Dim cmd41 As New SqlCommand(que11, conn)
                conn.Open()
                DDLVer.ClearSelection()
                DDLVer.DataSource = cmd41.ExecuteReader
                DDLVer.DataTextField = "Version And Lenght"
                DDLVer.DataValueField = "v_vpcode"
                DDLVer.DataBind()
                conn.Close()
                '--
                DDLVer.Items.Add("Version")
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

my problem is the DDLVer is resetting its index on EVERY POSTBACKS!

if tried putting if not ispostback before the functionality nothing happens but when i ran it in debug mode, vb skips it and proceeds to end if.

second, i tried putting different conditions such as if ispostback = true, if ispostback, if not ispostback =true, but no luck..

i have been developing asp.net pages for the last 2 months and this problem with ddlver is eating 1 week on my plotted schedule..

please if there are any workaround for this let me know.

i am tired looking and reading same articles over and over again..

*bows

here is my page load event

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True
        DDLVer.AppendDataBoundItems = True
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Call sess_load()
            Txtto.Enabled = False
            Txtbg.Enabled = False
            Txtencoded.Enabled = False
            DDLDate.Text = Date.Today.Date
            Txtfreq.Enabled = False
            Txtdate.Enabled = False
            Txtto1.Enabled = False
            TextBox4.Enabled = False
            Txtencoded.Enabled = False
        End If
```

as you can see, im not binding any ddl on page_load event

Comment: where is your page load? where you are binding your dropdowns?

Comment: Make sure that you have allowed viewstate

Comment: Please narrow down your problem. Nobody is going to read all that code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, sorry, but that the full code block of my cascading dropdowns. So, my problem is that, whenever the user chooses items from platform dropdown, agency will be populated according to its platform, and advertisers will be populated when there is a change of agency, product will be populated accordingly to its advertiser and lastly version will be populated accordingly to the product. but interestingly, when i clicked any object with postback property = true, the DDLVer reverts to its index 1.

Comment: Are you saying that, if you remove a single line of code, you no longer have the problem? If you can remove any code and still have the problem, then remove the code.

Comment: no, im saying is, whenever my DDLVer has a selectedvalue already, and when i click any object with autopostback, the ddlver will revert its selected value to its first index. this is frustating. any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

well, what is weird with this. the ddl has the same index value so on postbacks, they will revert to the very first item. so make sure that when you load items in ddls check the ID that you will put and make sure they are unique